# What does 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 represent in /etc/hosts ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

Every time i try to install some apache hadoop, hbase.

```
  127.0.0.1 localhost
    127.0.1.1 ubuntu-host
```

Generally it is being suggested that you comment the localhost part and use 127.0.0.1 ubuntu-host in your /etc/hosts file. What if i use both

`127.0.0.1 localhost, ubuntu-host`
is there any problem occurs with this. Moreover, it is being sugggested to disable the ipv6 in your cluster. What if i use the deafult host file and ipv6 enablbe. Does it lead to any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this [page](http://devving.com/?p=414). It explains beautifully that why does HBase care about /etc/hosts. As far as IPv6 is concerned, Hadoop is not currently supported on IPv6 networks. It has only been tested and developed on IPv4 stacks. Hadoop needs IPv4 to work, and only IPv4 clients can talk to the cluster.If your organisation moves to IPv6 only, you will encounter problems. See [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIPv6) for more details.

HTH

Comment: One more questions....even if i will not disable the ipv6....then by default shouldn't it use ipv4 stack?

Comment: Actually we cannot guarantee this always. Some Linux releases default to being IPv6 only. So, it's always better to turn it off. You are welcome.

Comment: the link is no longer active :(

Comment: @Newtopian This page Why does HBase care about /etc/hosts? is not available now but its content can be found at http://archive.is/t6L7E. Comment passed by [Echo Yuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4745344/echo-yuan), in this [Non answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44450659/5292302)